# Create a search animation sliding the text input part from the right to left

Tags: jquery, animation, search

I want to create a animation on search loop icon when hovering in it.First the loop only is displayed like this picture [image]

And when I will hover on the loop icon the text input must appear from the right inceasing its width to left and get 100% width. I tried this code

```
jQuery(".main_search .search-field").focusin(function() {
        jQuery(".main_search .screen-reader-text").css( "display", "none");
    });
    jQuery(".main_search .search-field").focusout(function() {
        jQuery(".main_search .screen-reader-text").css( "display", "block");
    });
```

But it looks like a bug.
HTMl structure

```
<div class="about_search">
                <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
        </form>                </div>
```

Comment: working code snippet can help people answer easily

Comment: yeah you are right, will prepare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed <kbd>**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/s0jfc57q/3/)**</kbd>:

```js
var CloseAnimationTimeout;

jQuery('.about_search .search-submit, .about_search .search-form label ').mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(CloseAnimationTimeout);
    jQuery('.about_search .search-form label').stop().animate({
      width: '94%'
    }, 'slow');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    CloseAnimationTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.about_search .search-form label').stop().animate({
        width: '0%'
      }, 'slow');
    }, 500);
  });
```

```css
.about_search .search-form {
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.about_search .search-form label {
  width: 0%;
  height: 38px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  border: 0;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}
.about_search .screen-reader-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.about_search .search-field {
  width: 100%%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
.about_search .search-submit {
  background: url('http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/themes/argentarius/images/loop.png') no-repeat #11213b;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-position: 9px 9px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -27px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0;
  float: right;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about_search">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/">
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
    <label style="width: 0%;"> <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>

      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EXPLANATION:**

- if you want the input to open up from the right, you need to anchor it to the right by setting its css to 'right:0;' and by floating it to the right.
- since floating stacks the elements by their order in the html, you need to move the button before the label for proper floating.
- the input inside the label needs to be stretched to 100% at all times, because you change the width of the label dynamically, the inout inside will adjust.
- since color of label is black, i changed the color of the input to white.
- changed the hover in/out handler from the form to the actual button + the label itself for better performance.
- added a delay to the closing animation using a timeout function to prevent it from stuttering and closing whenever you move the mouse

Comment: Hey @Banana I had created all that you described in the fiddle but in the site it looks like bug, here is the site [link](http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/site-map/) .Can you help me to understand the reason?

Comment: Strange, seems to work alright on my phine. Can you be more specific about the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: in the site when I hover on a loop and go a bit left I guess the label width gets 100% and goes to the bottom of the loop but I dont know the reason , I put the same as in the fiddle

Comment: I will check it when i get access to a computer

Comment: Hey @Banana I had updated the [fiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0jfc57q/4/) and added to label max-width:95% and issue solved

Comment: im glad to hear that you have resolved the issue. an alternative could be to set the label's position to absolute, and a `margin-right` to align it with the button.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted wont do anything with a picture since you can't focusin or focusout on a picture.

first you need to use

```
jQuery(".main_search .search-field").mouseover(function(){});
/* and*/
jQuery(".main_search .search-field").mouseout(function(){});
```

i made a [jsfiddle that does the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/rng67sLp/2/)

i hope that is what you were looking for

Sidenote: `$(element).stop()` is used to stop the animation from getting put into a queue. if you don't use `stop()` and a user keeps hovering over the div or picture the animations will queue up which is kinda annoying.

Comment: the `.search-field` suggests its not a picture but rather an input

Comment: @Banana I am using a wordpress search, it has search submit button and on hovering it the another text input needed to get width 0 to 100%

Comment: Just change the jQuery(element) to call on the img .. something like `$('#searchimage')` or if

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan a submit button is technically an input of type submit... zeropublix but my point still stands, the focusin/out is not performed on the picture itself.

Comment: @Banana true but my code is just an example code anyway. u can change it as much as u like to make it fit.

Comment: I had nearly this type of structure created in the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rng67sLp/2/) and it is not working @Banana

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan post a fiddle of what you have exactly, if this answer does not solve your issue, then i cant seem to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Here it is @Banana [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0jfc57q/) I need to get the text input to animate from right to left,