# Hovering another instance makes my text move

Tags: html, css

So i remade my website, and now i´m using flex layout, which makes my work a lot easier, i got a hover effect upon my input, so every time i hover a icon my input get shown but this input is moving to the right, when it was supposed to move to the left, which in case is making my layout move along with it
sorry for poor english, still learning,
here´s my code:

```css
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Roboto.zip");
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Open_Sans.zip");
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Playfair_Display.zip");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    display: flex; 
    background-color: red;
}

header ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair_Display', serif;
}

header #search-box {
    display: flex;
}


/*POSIÇÃO DOS ÍCONES*/
header #barsPosition {
    margin: auto 0 auto 3%;   
}

header #search-box {
    margin: auto 0 auto 15%;
}

header #inputBar {
    margin: 6% 0 auto 0;
}

header #searchPosition {
    margin: auto 0 auto 2%;
}

header h1 {
    margin: auto;
}

header #shopPosition {
    margin: auto 3% auto auto;
}
/*POSIÇÃO DOS ÍCONES*/



/*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
.barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
    width: 32px;
    height:32px;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/



/*RESPONSIVIDADE DO SITE*/
@media screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 3.0em;
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu40px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search40px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag40px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 40px;
        height:40px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 2.5em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu32px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search32px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag32px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 32px;
        height:32px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 2.0em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu24px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search24px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag24px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 24px;
        height:24px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu16px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search16px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag16px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 16px;
        height:16px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    header h1 {
        font-size: 1.0em;
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu12px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search12px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag12px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 12px;
        height:12px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 0.5em; 
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 0.5em; 
    }

}
/*RESPONSIVIDADE DO SITE*/



/*HEADER INPUT BAR*/
input {
    width: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in;
    border-bottom: 0.3px solid black;
}

header input#inputBar {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#search-box:hover > .inputBar {
    width: 200px;
}
/*HEADER INPUT BAR*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
      <title>Bunny&copy</title>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="author" content="Vitor N">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./global.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="./src/assets/image/logo.jpg">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <header>
              <i id="barsPosition" class="barsMenu"></i>

              <div id="search-box">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquise" class="inputBar">
                  <i id="searchPosition" class="searchIcon"></i>
              </div>

              <h1>BUNNY</h1>

              <i id="shopPosition" class="shoppingBag"></i>
      </header>
      <hr>
      <main>
      </main>
      <footer class="red"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well what it should do is go to the left instead of right

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895768/create-a-search-animation-sliding-the-text-input-part-from-the-right-to-left

Comment: @Brenden, seems like overkill to use jQuery for such a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it width already and use `transform: scale` property to get this done.
Increase or decrease the input width as per your need, and make sure it always have the sufficient width on left to grow.

```css
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Roboto.zip");
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Open_Sans.zip");
@import url("./src/assets/fonts/Playfair_Display.zip");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    display: flex; 
    background-color: red;
}

header ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair_Display', serif;
}

header #search-box {
    display: flex;
}


/*POSIÇÃO DOS ÍCONES*/
header #barsPosition {
    margin: auto 0 auto 3%;   
}

header #search-box {
    margin: auto 0 auto 15%;
}

header #inputBar {
    margin: 6% 0 auto 0;
}

header #searchPosition {
    margin: auto 0 auto 2%;
}

header h1 {
    margin: auto;
}

header #shopPosition {
    margin: auto 3% auto auto;
}
/*POSIÇÃO DOS ÍCONES*/



/*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
.barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
    width: 32px;
    height:32px;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/



/*RESPONSIVIDADE DO SITE*/
@media screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 3.0em;
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu40px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search40px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag40px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 40px;
        height:40px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 2.5em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu32px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search32px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag32px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 32px;
        height:32px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 2.0em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu24px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search24px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag24px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 24px;
        height:24px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em; 
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu16px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search16px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag16px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 16px;
        height:16px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    header h1 {
        font-size: 1.0em;
    }

    /*ÍCONES*/
    .barsMenu {background: url("./src/assets/icons/menu/menu12px.svg");}

    .searchIcon {background: url("./src/assets/icons/search/search12px.svg");}

    .shoppingBag {background: url("./src/assets/icons/shoppingbag/shopping-bag12px.svg");}
    /*ÍCONES*/

    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
    .barsMenu, .searchIcon, .shoppingBag {
        width: 12px;
        height:12px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*ATRIBUTO DOS ICONES*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 0.5em; 
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    header h1 {
      font-size: 0.5em; 
    }

}
/*RESPONSIVIDADE DO SITE*/



/*HEADER INPUT BAR*/
input {
position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in;
    border-bottom: 0.3px solid black;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    right: 0;
}
header #search-box {
    position: relative;
}
header input#inputBar {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#search-box:hover > .inputBar {
    transform: scale(1);
}
/*HEADER INPUT BAR*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
      <title>Bunny&copy</title>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="author" content="Vitor N">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./global.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="./src/assets/image/logo.jpg">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <header>
              <i id="barsPosition" class="barsMenu"></i>

              <div id="search-box">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquise" class="inputBar">
                  <i id="searchPosition" class="searchIcon"></i>
              </div>

              <h1>BUNNY</h1>

              <i id="shopPosition" class="shoppingBag"></i>
      </header>
      <hr>
      <main>
      </main>
      <footer class="red"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, good job, you're doing great! I like your semantic HTML. A few things to notice:

You wanna give a `max-width` to your search input, force it to be 100% of width and remove the unnecessary margin, like so:

```
    #search-box{
        max-width: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Make sure to adjust the values for mobile as well. Also, take a look at [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), it will suit your journey.

[Click here to view your updated code on Codepen.](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/QWyWdzp)